# How to connect MS office to TFS. I don't see the addin's

Tags: tfs

I am trying use the mass-update feature from projects and excel.
The add-in doesn't have Team addin to enable in MS excel.
I have access to TFS though.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to enable the add-in in Excel, then you need to install Visual Studio or at least install the [Team Explorer](http://Team%20Explorer%20installer). Generally the add-in will automatically enabled. If you still cannot see the Team ribbon, you can refer to below article for troubleshooting: [TFS-Office integration issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/office/tfs-office-integration-issues)

In your scenario, you can use the TFS Office Integration Installer. This new installer just includes the Office integration component (Excel, Project, etc) and is therefore lighter weight. See this blog : [TFS Office Integration Installer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2015/10/15/tfs-office-integration-installer/)

For 2017 version : [Team Foundation Server Office Integration 2017 (version 15.3)](https://www.heidoc.net/php/myvsdump_name.php?family=Visual%20Studio%202017%20%28version%2015.3%29&name=Team%20Foundation%20Server%20Office%20Integration%202017%20%28version%2015.3%29)

> Note that support for integrating TFS with Project Server is
>   deprecated for TFS 2017. However, synchronization support is provided
>   by a third part. See [Synchronize TFS with Project Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/tfs-ps-sync/sync-ps-tfs) for
>   details.
>
> ***Source here :  [Office integration tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/tools?toc=/vsts/work/work-items/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/work-items/breadcrumb/toc.json#office-integration-tools)***

Comment: The whole point of the TFS Office Integration Installer is that you don't have to install Team Explorer (or Visual Studio). See the first point in Brians post.

Comment: @Anil Acharya Have you resolved the issue? any update?